# When using the terminal to run a python autoclicker it shows No module named pynput.mouse

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to run 2 python projects at the same time, so I used the terminal to run them. When I run the code this error comes up

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
ImportError: No module named pynput.mouse
```

this is my code:

```
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
import time
import randomdelay = 0.07
button = Button.left
start_stop_key= KeyCode(char='g')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='o')

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                
                time.sleep(random.randint(-1,1) * 0.01 + self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I have uninstalled pynput and redid it with pip3 install pynput but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to do `pip install pynput`?

Comment: yes and also i can use f5 on the python idle to run i just cant use the terminal